# Android retrofit problem sending images in HTTP request

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

I'm trying to send images from camera as base64 string to my spring boot backend. I'm using retrofit. The images are located in an object. While debugging the images are loaded in and they are not null. Extra info size for each image is +-2 MB. When I'm trying to send them to my backend in my request they suddently become null. I don't know what I am doing wrong and I find it very weird that they were not null in my object that I send over HTTP. Any suggestions?

Service:

```
interface ImageApiService {

    @POST("imageObject")
    fun postNewAccidentStatement(@Body imageObject: ImageObject) : Deferred<ImageObject>
}
```

ImageObject class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "imageObject_table")
@SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.PRIMARY_KEY_FROM_EMBEDDED_IS_DROPPED)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
data class ImageObject(

 @TypeConverters(ImageConverter::class)
    @Json(name = "images")
    @Expose
    var imagesAccident: List<Image>? = null
)
```

Image class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "image_table")
data class Image (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = 0,
    var base64Img: String? = ""
)
```

Comment: Can you add some more code and details.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
 obj.put("file", "data:image/png;base64,"+imgbase64); 
 //add other object field

 //here call api retrofit and send obj.toString()
```

Comment: I want to send it over my request as a base64 string, not a file

Comment: Please, see my updated question including my classes so you see how I want to send it over HTTP as a List<Image> with property base64 String

Answer (score 0):

One possible ways to do it is to use hash map. So you have a base64 image which you had encoded.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("image", image);
```

And in your retrofit service do this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("image")
Call<ImageClass> getImage(@FieldMap HashMap<String, String> image);
```